# Basis for Product topology on $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and there at *the product topology* i have one doubt. There it is written that *the second condition is almost as easy, since the intersection of any two basis elements* $U_1\times V_1$ and $U_2\times V_2$ *is another basis element*.My problem is that **how does this prove the second condition?** For reference i am writing the condition they have given for a collection to be called a basis.

If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathbb B$ of subsets of $X$ such that :

1. For each $x\in X$ there is at least one basis element B containing x.
2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$ , then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$ .

After this they've defined the product topology as follows-

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. The product topology on $X\times Y$ is the topology having as basis the collection $\mathbb B$ of all sets of the form $U\times V$ where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an open subset of Y.

I am also attaching the screenshot of the section where i have highlighted the line in which i have the doubt. By the way i understand why the intersection of any two basis elements here is another basis element, i just can't understand how does this prove the second condition that they have given for a collection to be a basis.[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: The set $B_3$ needed is just the intersection $B_1\cap B_2$.

Answer (score 3):

In the condition we just pick $B_3= B_1 \cap B_2$ for **any** $x$ in it when $B_i = U_i \times V_i, i=1,2$. For open balls as a base in Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$ we have work to do, because the intersection of two balls need not be a ball, but contains one around each point of their intersection. The product open squares are closed under intersections (as e.g. open intervals in $\Bbb R$) and then the proof is easier.

Comment: So let me sum it up. We have $B_1=U_1\times V_1$ and $B_2=U_2\times V_2$. And $B_3$ is just $B_1\cap B_2$. Now our aim was to find any element $B_3$ from the basis itself that contains the point $x$ (that is in $B_1\cap B_2$ ) such that $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$. And here by proving that the intersection of any two basis elements is another basis element we have found one such element $B_3$ and because of the equality we can write $B_3 \subseteq B_1\cap B_2$. Is this the correct reasoning ? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @JasonLiam yes, essentially. For any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ we pick $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$ and the inclusion is trivial (even equality ).